# Autenticação e permissão para usuário

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Olá. Estou montando um sistema para cadastro e atualização, funcionaria da seguinte forma

Usuário loga e recebe uma tela para editar seu proprio cadastro, apenas.

Mas estou com uma dúvida. Como sou novo em **Rails**, venho conhecendo ferramentas para autorização e autenticção agora, como o devise e o pundir.

Considere a seguinte url

```
host/partner/id/edit
```

Como fazer com que somente o usuário que tenha o mesmo id da url seja capaz de editar esse cadastro?

Exemplo: 
`host/partner/200/edit` - somente o usuario com id 200 poderia ter acesso a essa pagina.

É duvida besta, mas como disse, sou iniciante em Rails.

Agradeço.

Answer (score 1):

Vc não precisa usar o pundit pra isso, se não quiser aprender agora.

Imagino que o usuário logue com o devise já, certo?

Logo, um simples

```
redirect_to root_path, error: "Sem acesso" if params[:id] != current_user.id
```

em um before_action no controller, resolve seu problema.